# Number formatting - Java

Tags: java, string, integer, format

I need to convert an integer so that a dash is inserted after two characters, for example 12-34-56.

The integer will be a randomly generated six digit number.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried and what isn't working otherwise your question will be marked down (as it has already). Take a look at the SO guidelines ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) before posting.

Comment: What's your effort so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 123456;
String result = String.format("%02d-%02d-%02d",
    (num / 10000), (num%10000 / 100), (num%100));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int num = 123456;
    char digits[] = Integer.toString(num).toCharArray();
    String what_you_want = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i += 2) {
        what_you_want += digits[i] + "" + digits[i + 1] + ((i < 4) ? "-" : "");
    }
    System.out.println(what_you_want);// output: 12-34-56
```